# UIAlertController with UIActivityIndicatorView not dismissing after comeback from new to previous view controller using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing `UIActivityIndicatorView` within `UIAlertController` for loading operations. I am using below code in common class and calling from other class files by using `self.loadinHubShow()` and `self.loadinHubDismiss()`. Now the issues is sometime  loading view UIAlertController with UIActivityIndicatorView not dismissing.

`For Example:` `Masterview` table cell click to go `details` page and comeback again masterview page. Now, the loading indicator I am calling for JSON data load but after `JSON` load not dismissing. How to fix this?

**Loading UIAlertController with UIActivityIndicatorView**

```
func loadinHubShow() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func loadinHubDismiss() {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

**Master ViewController Class**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
   self.loadinHubDismiss() // Sometimes not dismissing.
}
```

**Master ViewController JSON Load**

```
func JSONLoad() {

do {
                let decoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Demo.self,  from: data)
                let status = decoder.status
                if status == true {
                    self.sections = decoder.sections
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        self.loadinHubDismiss() // not hiding sometime
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        self.loadinHubDismiss()
                        self.Alert(Meesage: ServerValidation().servervalidation_msg)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    self.loadinHubDismiss()
                    self.Alert(Meesage: ServerError().servererror_msg)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Please, post you whole code.

Comment: @Augusto posting entire code very difficult. I updated my question hope it will help to understand my issue

Comment: Are you sure you are actually reaching that line of code? You have several `if` statements that could fail, as well as a `do / try / catch` block that could fail.... but you are not showing any code that would call `dismiss` in any of those cases.

Comment: @DonMag you're right. I am using within `do` and `catch` `if` statement. How to solve it?

Comment: @DonMag I updated question `do` and `catch` which is I am using. Sometime its not hiding and most of the time its working fine. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you getting any error / warning messages in Debug Console? Add a `print("calling dismiss")` to your `loadinHubDismiss()` func to make sure it's being called when you expect it.

Comment: @DonMag as per your mentioned above I tried `print("calling dismiss")`its printing. I mean its called.

Comment: Try adding this before calling dismiss ... `guard self.presentedViewController != nil else { fatalError("No presentedViewController !!!") }` See if that gets triggered.

Comment: @DonMag No, Its not triggered. May I know why its happening?

Comment: @DonMag may I know why its happening?

Comment: Really tough to say... You've only posted small bits of code which don't properly explain what you're doing. When are you calling `loadinHubShow()`? When are you calling `JSONLoad()`? Maybe take a look at [mcve].

Comment: @DonMag I am calling `JSONLoad()` from `ViewWillAppear`. It will call every time view appear and it will load the data into tableview until the loading screen will be appear after JSON data load success need to dismiss. Its working well some time but some time not dismissing. If I do custom loading UI can I avoid this issue?

Comment: @DonMag Its all happening by AlertController with ActivityIndicator. If I create custom loading UI. It will work fine I think.

Comment: @TestApp - You've probably seen in the documentation: ***`Important`*** 
*`The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.`* So... I don't know if that could be causing your issue, but you're probably better off using a custom loading UI anyway.

Comment: @DonMag do you have any sample for custom loading UI. Please post here.